# Python convert string to object

Tags: python, pandas, string, sqlalchemy

I am using pandas/sql alchemy to write a table to an sql database.

Here is some sample code below:

```
df.to_sql('table', connection, schema=None, dtype={
    'id': sa.types.VARCHAR(length=100),
    'value1': sa.types.Float(),
    'value2': sa.types.Float()})
```

I have a csv file where the data type for each column is defined, I would like to be able to read the csv file using pandas and then convert the table to a dictionary which would be passed to the `to_sql()` method.

If I were to do that directly, the data type, for example `sa.types.VARCHAR(length=100)` would appear as a string. How can I convert this string so that it can be passed as an appropriate data type.

To clarify if i read the data from a csv table, the dtype dictionary will look like this:

```
{'id': 'sa.types.VARCHAR(length=100)'}
```

instead of the current:

```
{'id': sa.types.VARCHAR(length=100)}
```

Comment: What is the appropriate data type? Why don't you just use that instead of `VARCHAR`?

Comment: What do you mean by "the data type would appear as a string"?

Comment: I added a clarification

Comment: I think what you're seeing is just the way the `sa.types` class represents itself. It's not really a string.

Comment: It's a class object, they don't have literal representations like strings and numbers. They chose to use a string-like appearance rather than `<sa.types ...>` notation.

Comment: @Barmar I don't understand what you mean, when I set the type object as a string like: {'id': 'sa.types.VARCHAR(length=100)'} i get and error saying ValueError: The type of id is not a SQLAlchemy type

Answer (score 0):

This solution is hacky and I have to believe there's a better way if we had all of the information, but short of that, here goes.

I would create a dictionary similar to:

```
type_dict = {
   'VARCHAR' : sa.types.VARCHAR,
   'Float'   : sa.types.Float, 
   ... }
```

Then, break up that string to get the main info you're looking for (I'm sure there's a better regex way to do this, but it's past my bedtime):

```
dtype = string.split('(')[0].split('.')[-1]
var   = string.split('(')[1].split('=').split(')')[0]
```

Then:

```
sql_dict = { 'id' : type_dict[dtype](var) }
```